# I'm building a SFTP/FTPS plugin for my app that can login to FTPS or SFTP servers. What authentication properties are different for FTPS and SFTP?

Tags: sftp, ftp-server

My application needs to access files from a remote FTPS or SFTP server depending on what my app user wants to connect to. I need to be able to access file content in a folder or create a folder.
1) What login properties differ for an FTPS and SFTP server that a user must enter?
2) Is there any way I can detect if it is an SFTP or FTPS server?

Comment: Have you googled it? There seems to be quite a few posts about SFTP versus FTPS. Ok, there probably isn't one in which it answers to your questions in the 1st paragraph, but still. I'm basically suggesting it would be nice if you narrow your question after some research.

Comment: @Irnzcig, I tried googling for difference in login properties. I see differences in the SSH and SSL protocols and that they are completely different. My app needs to be able to connect to both and I want to know what properties I can collect from my user and make a decision to connect to SFTP or FTPS.

Comment: What do you mean by "authentication properties"? Are you referring to some particular library/framework? Your question way too vague.

Comment: I guess he means the credentials such as username or password... However, SFTP/SSH supports [`keyboard-interactive` authentication method](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4256#section-3.1) which makes it possible for the server to ask for *anything*, although most servers only use it to ask for username and password.

Comment: And as for the second question - FTPS and SFTP are different protocols that use different TCP ports. SFTP/SSH runs on port 22, FTP and FTP over explicit TLS/SSL on port 21 and FTP over implicit TLS/SSL on port 990. To detect whether a server might support each of these protocols, you can simply try connecting to these ports (and possibly attempt some communication to make sure it's the right protocol). However, you won't know for sure whether a server supports SFTP unless you actually establish an SSH session and authenticate.

Comment: @LukasPokorny, you're right. I mean what fields should the user fill out for my app to authenticate and establish a connection to his/her SFTP/FTPS server and pull data into my app. Is it host, username, password for both SFTP and FTPS? Who decides these fields?

Comment: Well, with `keyboard-interactive` authentication method, an SFTP/SSH server can prompt for *whatever fields it wants* (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4256#page-5 for details). In practice, almost all servers just prompt for a password (and most use `password` authentication method for that), but there are actually SFTP/SSH servers out there that do ask for other information as well (this is useful for multi-factor authentication, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SFTP doesn't have any authentication. SFTP protocol is supposed to be used over SSH connection, thus it relies on SSH for authentication. So all authentication mechanisms of SSH apply. The list of such mechanisms is extensive - you can authenticate using password, a private key ("public-key authentication"), X.509 certificate (not a popular option), keyboard-interactive (challenge-response) dialog, also via GSS-API you can use Kerberos and possibly other mechanisms. FTPS as FTP-over-TLS can also use various mechanisms. FTP uses username/password by default, but potentially one can implement some tricky mechanisms using SITE command. TLS protocol includes client-side authentication using X.509 certificates, pre-shared symmetric keys, plain PKI keys, OpenPGP keys.
2. SFTP and FTP/FTPS are *completely* different protocols. Servers run on different ports. If you want to implement protocol autodetection, you can try the following: connect to the server, and if it sends a welcome SSH message within 200-500 ms, you know that it's an SSH (and potentially SFTP) server. If it sends a welcome FTP message, it's an FTP server (this includes explicit TLS mode of FTPS). If it sends nothing, then it *can* be a TLS server and you can have implicit FTPS over this connection.

Comment: Thank you. About 1, you say that the list of mechanisms is extensive. Are these mechanisms decided by those who setup the server? What are the minimum fields that a server owner must provide to my app so I can connect to the server and pull content? (Clearly, I'm new to this. In simple words, like how I can allow a user to authenticate using OAuth from facebook for my app to pull information from his profile, I want to do the same thing with my app's FTPS or SFTP plugin)

Comment: @eechpeech The mechanisms are set up by the server (or its admins). The standards define a limited set of mechanisms (the one I've listed) but there's a room for custom extensions. Such extensions, however, must be supported by both client and server software in a uniform manner. To address your particular need, I doubt that you could use OAuth for FTPS or SFTP authentication, because I have yet to see the server (or at least a standard) that offers this functionality.